# Error: [$compile:ctreq], Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an input tag as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="swap($parent.$index,$index)" ng-model="checked">
```

This tag is in nested `ng-repeat`. When I remove the `ng-model`, I got this error:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange

Does `ng-change` directive need `ng-model` directive?

Comment: That's exactly what the detailed error message, that you obtain when you click on the link, or when not using the minified angular, says: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely you need ng-model here, because ng-change needs to detect the changes on the model,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="swap($parent.$index,$index)" ng-model="checked">
```

From **Docs**

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be ... Note, this directive requires
>   ngModel to be present.

**[`ng-change Directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)**